# Prevent line-wraps of code blocks using jekyll, kramdown, and rouge

Tags: css, jekyll, jekyll-extensions, kramdown, rouge

Using kramdown and rouge for markdown syntax-highlighting in a jekyll blog, I'd like to prevent long lines of code from wrapping onto a new line. I'd like to be able to use a horizontal scrollbar to reveal the rest of the content.

Here is the jekyll config:

```
markdown: kramdown
kramdown:
  input: GFM
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
```

I'm using the `base16.solarized.dark` css theme generated by the `rougify` command.

Here is an example code usage:

`````
```` js
console.log("some code") // and a really really long long long comment which i'd like to not wrap onto the next line
````
`````

Comment: Impossible to debug without seeing your css stack. Can you provide a repository link ?

Comment: https://github.com/data-creative/data-creative.github.io/ using twitter bootstrap and base16.solarized.dark for css - thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Boostrap is adding a `white-space: pre-wrap` rule in order to help code block readability.

If you want you code block to avoid this wrap, you can edit your **css/data-creative.css** and add

```
pre code{
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: I tried setting this property before but maybe I was applying it on the wrong element/ set of elements. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have somewhere a CSS rule that for the `code` element sets `white-space: pre-wrap`. Add the following rule to override it:

```
code {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it like this:

```
pre {
    ...
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```